# Why rsync with jump host and sshpass not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, rsync, sshpass

I'm trying to rsync with 'sshpass' and using jump host to transform a file.

The command I am using is -

`rsync -azv -e 'sshpass -p passwordToTargetHost ssh -oProxyCommand="sshpass -p passwordToJumpHost user@JumpHost" user@TargetHost' :/path/to/target /path/to/originFile`

But I am getting -

> -bash: line 1: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1: command not found

Any help?

Comment: If the question has nothing to do with software development, then it is wrong here. Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: I've asked that question there as well, Thanks!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/92981/paswordless-rsync-over-ssh-without-key-authentication-un-safe